# Trying to create a new linked server from the script of an available linked sever in another server. The connection test fails on some servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

This is the linked server script generated by the sql server itself. I used this script to create the same linked server on other servers. On some of them when I execute the connection test, it gives me "microsoft sql server, error: 18456" as if I have entered the remote login and password part wrong but I'm sure their correct for the 192.168.0.72 server and also the connection test succeeds on some other servers with the same credentials when I test it. Below is my generated script from the original linked server:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [TEST]    Script Date: 8/22/2020 3:42:31 PM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'TEST', @srvproduct=N'192.168.0.72', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'.'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'TEST',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'sa',@rmtpassword='########'

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'TEST', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Comment: The `@datasrc` parameter should specify the remote server name or IP address. It looks  the remote IP is in the wrong place (`@srvproduct`) and `@datasrc` specifies the local instance instead of remote server.

Comment: Dan Guzman is right, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql for more details.